# How to access index page?

Tags: java, html, servlets, indexing

I'm new in the servlets thing, and I've seen that there's a lot of code that explains how to make a complete road through the request-response of the servlet, but most of cases they use the `response.getWritter().println("something")`, but, I've seen that there's another ways to generate html content, like the index page that should charge by default when the servlet is accessed. I have a basic example of a servlet and the web.xml, I want to know if you can help me to understand what I can do to make the index.html show when I type `localhost:8280/persistence-with-jdbc2/...`

this is the basic of the servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2")

public class PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2.class);

    private PersonDAO personDAO;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

        System.out.println("init");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //What can I use here?
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            // test code
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.getWriter().println(
                "Persistence operation failed with reason: "
                     + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("Persistence operation failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**and the web.xml content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>persistence-with-jdbc2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2</display-name>
      <servlet-name>PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.sap.cloud.sample.persistence.PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>PersistenceWithJDBCServlet2</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDB</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can just redirect it to what ever webadress you want.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/yourwebAdress/index.html");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are creating the index page like index.jsp and put this following sample code like as:

```
<body>
<jsp:forward page="/UserController?action=listUser" />
</body>
```

And call this index page in the web.xml page, like

```
   <display-name>Simple1</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UserController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UserController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pro3.controller.UserController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

And add this one in controller page:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
```